# Read large .sql file in Java and write the data in database.

Tags: database

I have to read a large. Sql file (50 GB) in Java and write the content in a database. I tried it with small files (200 MB), it works but only for the first file,  by the second file it becomes too slowly and doesn't terminate correctly (OOM Java heap space) I changed the xmx to 6144m but it still slowly by the first file. Can I refresh the memory after every iteration.

Comment: Show us the code you use to read and write.  I speculate that you are storing too much information in memory, leading to the heap problem in Java.

Comment: It sounds like you can read the file line by line into Java. That should not need to consume much memory. Also, why is Java involved at all? Cannot you process the SQL with the database's own tools?

Comment: As @Thilo pointed check out import tools such as SQL loader for this kind of job.